# How to dynamic_cast in classes with circular dependency?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, dynamic-cast

I want to dynamically cast a class:

> A.h:

```
class A
{
};
```

> B.h:

```
class B
    : public A
{
public:
    void foo(A *a)
    {
        C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a);
    }
};
```

> C.h:

```
class C
    : public A
{
public:
    void foo(A *a)
    {
        B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    }
};
```

> main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

int main()
{
}
```

When I compile, I get the following error:

> 'C' : undeclared identifier

I think it is because of circular dependency between classes `B` and `C`.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: tnx, I want to call functions of child of A in another child of A.(not inherited functions but other functions that are specific to each child)

Comment: @mahdi.Lotfi Why do you need to `dynamic_cast` a pointer of `A*` into a pointer `B*` in a function of class `C`?

Answer (score 2):

> A.h

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H

class A
{
public:
    int x{ 0 };

    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};

// definition
class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() override {}

    void foo(A* a);
};

// definition
class C
    : public A
{
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() override {}

    void foo(A* a);
};

#endif _A_H
```

> A.cpp

```
#include "A.h" // NECESSARY !
#include <iostream>

void
B::
foo(A* a)
{
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a);
    if (c)
    {
        std::cout <<
            "c->x = "
            << c->x
            << std::endl;
    }
}

void
C::
foo(A* a)
{
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    if (b)
    {
        std::cout <<
            "b->x = "
            << b->x
            << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.x = 1;
    C c;
    c.x = 2;

    b.foo(&c);
    c.foo(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

Use the following command to compile and execute, if you are using `gcc`:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I. -o main A.cpp main.cpp \
  && ./main
```

Upon running the program, you will get the following output from the prompt:

```
c->x = 2
b->x = 1
```

Comment: thank you for your response.
I want to implement class A and B and C in different .h file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved.
The solution was separation of header file and implementation file .cpp and include all .h file in .cpp file